# an algorithm to find the minimum size set cover for the Set-cover problem

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages

In the Set Covering problem, we are given a universe U, such that |U|=n, and sets S1,……,Sk are subsets of U. A set cover is a collection C of some of the sets from S1,……,Sk whose union is the entire universe U.

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that will find the minimum number of set cover so that I can show that the greedy algorithm for set covering sometimes finds more sets.

Following is what I came up with:

repeat for each set.
1. Cover<-Seti (i=1,,,n)
2. if a set is not a subset of any other sets, then take take that set into cover.

but it's not working for some instances.
Please help me figure out an algorithm to find the minimum set cover.

I'm still having problem find this algorithm online. Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Um. The greedy algorithm doesn't always find more sets. For example in the trivial case where the subsets are all disjoint, it finds exactly the minimum, i.e. all of them.

Comment: You are right. I corrected my question.

Comment: but do you have any suggestion on how to come up with an algorithm that will always find the minimum number of sets? Thanks

Comment: @user491753: no, I don't know of a way to find the size of the minimum cover any more simply than finding the minimum cover itself. Even just to determine in general whether the greedy algorithm is optimal for a given input: no idea, sorry. Just hoping to clarify the question before others who have a clue get here :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set cover is NP-hard, so it's unlikely that there'll be an algorithm much more efficient than looking at all possible combinations of sets, and checking if each combination is a cover.

Basically, look at all combinations of 1 set, then 2 sets, etc. until they form a cover.

**EDIT**

This is an example pseudocode. Note that I do not claim that this is efficient. I simply claim that there isn't a much more efficient algorithm (algorithms will be worse than polynomial time unless something really cool is discovered)

```
for size in 1..|S|:
    for C in combination(S, size):
          if (union(C) == U) return C
```

where `combination(K, n)` returns all possible sets of size `n` whose elements come from `K`.

**EDIT**

However, I'm not too sure why you need an algorithm to find the minimum. In the question you state that you want to show that the greedy algorithm for set covering sometimes finds more sets. But this is easily achieved via a counterexample (and a counterexample is shown in the wikipedia entry for set cover). So I am quite puzzled.

**EDIT**

A possible implementation of `combination(K, n)` is:

```
if n == 0: return [{}] //a list containing an empty set
r = []
for k in K:
    K = K \ {k} // remove k from K.
    for s in combination(K, n-1):
        r.append(union({k}, s))
return r
```

But in combination with the cover problem, one probably wants to perform the test of coverage from the base case `n == 0` instead. Well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please show me the pseudo code. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: because I wrote a program that uses greedy alg. to find the min-cover and I just wanted to write another program that finds min-cover without greedy method but not so much efficient

Comment: Still don't understand. What is the objective? Is it to show that the greedy algorithm doesn't always get the minimum cover?

Comment: yes. Just wanted to show that greedy alg. does not always find the min. cover. Do you know where I can get a problem in java that finds combinations of sets.

Comment: Then, all you need is a counterexample. There is one in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem (at the "Greedy algorithm" section). It shows that the greedy algorithm does not find the minimum cover for that particular problem.

Comment: thanks. what would be the run time of the algorithm you provided?

Comment: it is extremely horribly factorial time. do not use for any largish size. and there is plenty of room for improvement, although there're no known ways to get it into polynomial time at the moment.

Comment: so the run time is O(n!)? Since we have 2n-1 possible combinations to check. shouldn't the run time for the alg. you provided be O((2^(n))m*n)

Comment: oops. yes. 2^|S| sounds right. I guess m = |U|? unlike in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try Donald E. Knuth algorithm-X for exact set coverage, using a sparse matrix. Must be adapted a little to solve minimum set cover problems also.