# Branch and bound algorithm for the Set Cover problem?

Tags: java, algorithm

Can someone pleas share with me a java program that uses the Branch and bound method to solve the Set Cover problem? 
Following is what I have so far. So at each stage, the algorithm is supposed to take a set and get two instances of the problem: 1.select the first set from the array list 2. don't take the first set from the arraylist.
At this point I'm stuck on how to start the branch and bound.

import java.util.*;

```
public class BranchAndBound {
    static int bestSoFar=100;
    static int count=0;
    public static void main(String args[]){

    //create the universe
    int numU = 10;
    MySets universe = new MySets();
    for(int i=1;i<=numU;i++){
           universe.add(i);
    }

    //create each set
    MySets s1 = new MySets();
    MySets s2 = new MySets();
    MySets s3 = new MySets();
    MySets s4 = new MySets();
    MySets s5 = new MySets();

    ArrayList<MySets> s=new ArrayList<MySets>();
    //elements
    s1.add(1);s1.add(2);s1.add(3);s1.add(8);s1.add(9);s1.add(10);
    s2.add(1);s2.add(2);s2.add(3);s2.add(4);s2.add(5);
    s3.add(4);s3.add(5);s3.add(7);
    s4.add(5);s4.add(6);s4.add(7);
    s5.add(6);s5.add(7);s5.add(8);s5.add(9);s5.add(10);

    s.add(s1);s.add(s2);s.add(s3);s.add(s4);s.add(s5);
    branchAndBound(universe,s,0);

    }

    public static void branchAndBound(MySets U,ArrayList<MySets> listSets,int countSelected){
        MySets universe = new MySets();
        universe.addAll(U);

        ArrayList<MySets> s=new ArrayList<MySets>();
        s.addAll(listSets);

        MySets selectedSet= new MySets();

        selectedSet.addAll(listSets.get(0));
        count++;

        universe.removeAll(selectedSet);//the universe now contains the elements still need to be covered
        listSets.remove(0);//remove the first elemeent from the list

        displaySet(selectedSet, "selected set");
        displaySet(universe, "universe");

        while(!universe.isEmpty() && !listSets.isEmpty()){
            branchAndBound(universe,listSets,count);
        }
    }




public static void displaySet(MySets s, String name){
    System.out.print(name+"==>");
    Iterator it=s.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      Integer value=(Integer)it.next();
      System.out.print(+value+" ");
    }//while
    System.out.println();
}//displaySet
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you asked a similar question earlier and a related one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282003/an-algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-size-set-cover-for-the-set-cover-problem). As pointed out there, Set Covering is NP-Hard. So, no polynomial algorithm is known to exist for it. When you abstract away from the specifics of the problem, it is an integer program (IP). So, you can use any general purpose IP solver such as the one provided in MS-Excel. All general integer programming problems are solved using branch-and-bound method. So, you do not need one specifically for Set Covering alone. All you need to do is to formulate the set covering problem as an integer program and provide it to the solver which should take care of the rest. Folks on SO are unlikely to have a ready-made code available to share with you. Integer Programming/Linear Programming (which forms the basis for integer programming) codes are quite detailed and specialized.

Comment: Yes I did. There are no poly-time alg. for set cover to find the min. set cover, I agree. but we can design branch and bound alg. to find the min, which will not be poly time but it will generate a min. set cover.

Comment: @user: I dont understand why you need to "design" a B&B algorithm. I can see you have the `homework` tag on...I am really surprised you have to design a B&B algorithm from scratch for your homework. Is this to be programmed so that it can solve any sized problem? Or do you have a small-sized problem for which you need to show (by hand) the steps a brach-and-bound algorithm would follow in solving it?

Comment: I really did not put that homework tag on my question. Someone else did and apologize for the confusion. It is not a homework problem. I know that it is a np hard problem, I'm trying to write a java program that finds the minimum cover  using B&B and I have no idea where to start. I'm updating my posting to show what I've written so far. Thanks so much

Comment: @user: If this is not homework, then you are trying to reinvent the wheel here...there are many IP solvers out there...MS Solver and ILOG CPLEX to name a few...why do you want to code a B&B solver from scratch? Simply present the model to an off-the-shelf solver.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a lot of people have tried solving this problem using B&B method for themselves before.